# How to query registry key and write computer description to a log file

Tags: batch-file

I need to query the registry for

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters\srvcomment
```

I need to write the value data from the `srvcomment` string to a log file `C:\Log.txt`.

I can query the registry but I have not been able to figure out how to use the if statement to add the value data to the log file. I would really appreciate help.

This is what I have so far

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters" /v "srvcomment" | Find "REG_SZ">>C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Test\"Computer Description".txt
```

I only need the *Computer Description* from the registry. Unless someone knows if there is any other way to capture the information from anywhere else on the system via .bat file.

Comment: This is what I have so far.

Comment: REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters" /v "srvcomment" | Find "REG_SZ">>C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Test\"Computer Description".txt

Comment: I only need the Computer Description from the registry. Unless someone knows if there is any other way to capture the information from anywhere else on the system via .bat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write yourself an Batch Script with those two lines.
Gives you only the ValueDate of the Value srvcomment.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters" /v srvcomment') DO SET ServerName=%%B
ECHO %ServerName% > C:\ServerName.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is:

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters" /V "srvcomment" 1>nul 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Computer "%COMPUTERNAME%" has no description.>"%TEMP%\Log.txt"
) else (
    for /F "tokens=2*" %%C in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters" /V "srvcomment" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /C:srvcomment') do echo Computer "%COMPUTERNAME%" has description "%%D".>"%TEMP%\Log.txt"
)
```

Something different than `"%TEMP%\Log.txt"` should be used for the log file. `C:\Log.txt` is also not good as usually the root of drive C: is write-protected for non administrators since Windows Vista.

The batch file first uses command `reg` to check if string value `srvcomment` exists at all in Windows registry. Output to standard output and standard error streams are both redirected to device NUL to suppress them. Computers with no computer description do not have this string value in registry. In this case an appropriate information for the computer is written into the log file.

But if string value `srvcomment` exists in Windows registry, command `reg` is executed once again with output passed to tool `findstr` to get just the line containing `srvcomment`. The pipe character `|` must be escaped here with `^` as used in a command within command `for`.

Output by `reg` filtered by `findstr` is:

```
    srvcomment  REG_SZ  computer description
```

The `for` loop splits a line based on a list of delimiters. The space and the horizontal tab characters are by default the only delimiters. What we need here is the string after `REG_SZ` up to end of line even if this string contains spaces. `REG_SZ` is the second string with space used as delimiter. Because of specifying `tokens=2*` the second string is assigned to placeholder variable `A`, and everything else starting from third string to end of line to placeholder variable `B`.

So all needed to get written now the computer description to the log file is referencing value of placeholder variable `B` in `echo` command redirected to the log file.

For more details on the used commands run in a command prompt window one after the other:

```
reg query /?
findstr /?
for /?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reg /query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters\srvcomment"  > "c:\Log.txt"
```

?

Comment: I tried it. Unfortunately it didn't work. However, you did help me get one step closer.

Comment: @rodr - try to execute this with Admin permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command in a batch file which you might need to reformat

```
wmic /OUTPUT:c:\log.txt os get description /VALUE
```

or the following Powershell command

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Description | Out-File -FilePath C:\log.txt
```